# Libreoffice android build on Ubuntu

Tags: libreoffice

I'm trying to build libreoffice android on ubuntu15.04(64 bit),I followed https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Android#How_to_build_it, but when I run 'make', I got error

```
checking for a usable iconv... no
checking for FT_Get_Next_Char... yes
checking for FT_Get_BDF_Property... yes
checking for FT_Get_PS_Font_Info... yes
checking for FT_Has_PS_Glyph_Names... yes
checking for FT_Get_X11_Font_Format... yes
checking for FT_Select_Size... yes
checking for FT_Bitmap_Size.y_ppem... yes
checking expat.h usability... yes
checking expat.h presence... yes
checking for expat.h... yes
checking for XML_SetDoctypeDeclHandler... no
configure: WARNING: Cannot find usable expat library. Trying to use libxml2 as fallback.
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for LIBXML2... yes
checking for docbook2html... no
DOCMAN3 FcAtomicCreate.3 FcAtomicLock.3 FcAtomicNewFile.3 FcAtomicOrigFile.3 FcAtomicReplaceOrig.3 FcAtomicDeleteNew.3 FcAtomicUnlock.3 FcAtomicDestroy.3 FcBlanksCreate.3 FcBlanksDestroy.3 FcBlanksAdd.3 FcBlanksIsMember.3 FcCacheDir.3 FcCacheCopySet.3 FcCacheSubdir.3 FcCacheNumSubdir.3 FcCacheNumFont.3 FcCharSetCreate.3 FcCharSetDestroy.3 FcCharSetAddChar.3 FcCharSetCopy.3 FcCharSetEqual.3 FcCharSetIntersect.3 FcCharSetUnion.3 FcCharSetSubtract.3 FcCharSetMerge.3 FcCharSetHasChar.3 FcCharSetCount.3 FcCharSetIntersectCount.3 FcCharSetSubtractCount.3 FcCharSetIsSubset.3 FcCharSetFirstPage.3 FcCharSetNextPage.3 FcCharSetCoverage.3 FcCharSetNew.3 FcConfigCreate.3 FcConfigReference.3 FcConfigDestroy.3 FcConfigSetCurrent.3 FcConfigGetCurrent.3 FcConfigUptoDate.3 FcConfigHome.3 FcConfigEnableHome.3 FcConfigBuildFonts.3 FcConfigGetConfigDirs.3 FcConfigGetFontDirs.3 FcConfigGetConfigFiles.3 FcConfigGetCache.3 FcConfigGetCacheDirs.3 FcConfigGetFonts.3 FcConfigGetBlanks.3 FcConfigGetRescanInterval.3 FcConfigSetRescanInterval.3 FcConfigAppFontAddFile.3 FcConfigAppFontAddDir.3 FcConfigAppFontClear.3 FcConfigSubstituteWithPat.3 FcConfigSubstitute.3 FcFontMatch.3 FcFontSort.3 FcFontRenderPrepare.3 FcFontList.3 FcConfigFilename.3 FcConfigParseAndLoad.3 FcNameRegisterConstants.3 FcNameUnregisterConstants.3 FcNameGetConstant.3 FcNameConstant.3 FcDirCacheUnlink.3 FcDirCacheValid.3 FcDirCacheLoad.3 FcDirCacheRead.3 FcDirCacheLoadFile.3 FcDirCacheUnload.3 FcFileScan.3 FcFileIsDir.3 FcDirScan.3 FcDirSave.3 FcFontSetCreate.3 FcFontSetDestroy.3 FcFontSetAdd.3 FcFontSetList.3 FcFontSetMatch.3 FcFontSetPrint.3 FcFontSetSort.3 FcFontSetSortDestroy.3 FcPatternFormat.3 FcFreeTypeCharIndex.3 FcFreeTypeCharSet.3 FcFreeTypeCharSetAndSpacing.3 FcFreeTypeQuery.3 FcFreeTypeQueryFace.3 FcInitLoadConfig.3 FcInitLoadConfigAndFonts.3 FcInit.3 FcFini.3 FcGetVersion.3 FcInitReinitialize.3 FcInitBringUptoDate.3 FcLangSetCreate.3 FcLangSetDestroy.3 FcLangSetCopy.3 FcLangSetAdd.3 FcLangSetCompare.3 FcLangSetContains.3 FcLangSetEqual.3 FcLangSetHash.3 FcLangSetHasLang.3 FcLangSetGetLangs.3 FcGetLangs.3 FcLangGetCharSet.3 FcMatrixInit.3 FcMatrixCopy.3 FcMatrixEqual.3 FcMatrixMultiply.3 FcMatrixRotate.3 FcMatrixScale.3 FcMatrixShear.3 FcObjectSetCreate.3 FcObjectSetAdd.3 FcObjectSetDestroy.3 FcObjectSetBuild.3 FcNameRegisterObjectTypes.3 FcNameUnregisterObjectTypes.3 FcNameGetObjectType.3 FcPatternCreate.3 FcPatternDuplicate.3 FcPatternReference.3 FcPatternDestroy.3 FcPatternEqual.3 FcPatternEqualSubset.3 FcPatternFilter.3 FcPatternHash.3 FcPatternAdd.3 FcPatternAddWeak.3 FcPatternAdd-Type.3 FcPatternGet.3 FcPatternGet-Type.3 FcPatternBuild.3 FcPatternDel.3 FcPatternRemove.3 FcPatternPrint.3 FcDefaultSubstitute.3 FcNameParse.3 FcNameUnparse.3 FcUtf8ToUcs4.3 FcUcs4ToUtf8.3 FcUtf8Len.3 FcUtf16ToUcs4.3 FcUtf16Len.3 FcIsLower.3 FcIsUpper.3 FcToLower.3 FcStrCopy.3 FcStrDowncase.3 FcStrCopyFilename.3 FcStrCmp.3 FcStrCmpIgnoreCase.3 FcStrStr.3 FcStrStrIgnoreCase.3 FcStrPlus.3 FcStrFree.3 FcStrDirname.3 FcStrBasename.3 FcStrSetCreate.3 FcStrSetMember.3 FcStrSetEqual.3 FcStrSetAdd.3 FcStrSetAddFilename.3 FcStrSetDel.3 FcStrSetDestroy.3 FcStrListCreate.3 FcStrListNext.3 FcStrListDone.3 FcValueDestroy.3 FcValueSave.3 FcValuePrint.3 FcValueEqual.3
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating fontconfig/Makefile
config.status: creating fc-lang/Makefile
config.status: creating fc-glyphname/Makefile
config.status: creating fc-case/Makefile
config.status: creating fc-arch/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating conf.d/Makefile
config.status: creating fc-cache/Makefile
config.status: creating fc-cat/Makefile
config.status: creating fc-list/Makefile
config.status: creating fc-match/Makefile
config.status: creating fc-query/Makefile
config.status: creating fc-scan/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/version.sgml
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating fontconfig.spec
config.status: creating fontconfig.pc
config.status: creating fontconfig-zip
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
Making all in fontconfig
Making all in fc-case
Making all in fc-lang
Making all in fc-glyphname
Making all in fc-arch
Making all in src
  CC     fcxml.lo
libtool: compile:  /home/sc/core/external/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -mthumb -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -L/home/sc/core/external/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a --sysroot=/home/sc/core/external/android-ndk/platforms/android-15/arch-arm -Wno-psabi -fuse-ld=gold -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I.. -I../src -I/home/sc/core/workdir/UnpackedTarball/freetype/instdir/include/freetype2 -I/home/sc/core/workdir/UnpackedTarball/freetype/instdir/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -fno-strict-aliasing -DFC_CACHEDIR=\"/usr/local/var/cache/fontconfig\" -DFONTCONFIG_PATH=\"/usr/local/etc/fonts\" -DHAVE_GCC_VISIBILITY_FEATURE -fvisibility=hidden -MT fcxml.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fcxml.Tpo -c fcxml.c -o fcxml.o
In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810:0,
                 from fcxml.c:32:
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:28:19: fatal error: iconv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <iconv.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:468: recipe for target 'fcxml.lo' failed
make[5]: *** [fcxml.lo] Error 1
Makefile:354: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:447: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
Makefile:330: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have 2 question:

1.What steps should I do but I don't?

2.I just want see office documents,there is a need to establish the whole environment?

Comment: You might be better served over at http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Doesn't ubuntu come with libreoffice?

Comment: @LachlanGoodhew-Cook ok,Thanks:)@NightShadeQueen Yes It have, but I want to develop it